# Save row colour after closing form

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I got this for saving all data when closing the form.

```
Public Class Form1

Dim table As New DataTable("Table")
ReadOnly p As String = Path.Combine("C:\test.xml")
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
    If Not File.Exists(p) Then
        table.Columns.Add("Company", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Date", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
        table.Columns.Add("Code", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Position", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Note", Type.GetType("System.String"))
        table.Columns.Add("Solved", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
    Else
        table.ReadXml(p)
    End If
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
End Sub
```

I was using this for mark solved row:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Solved").Value = DateTime.Now
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```

And this for "repair solved row" button:

```
 Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
    DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Solved").Value = ""
    DataGridView1.DataSource = table
    DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
 End Sub
```

The problem is, that my saving doesn't save this coloured row, it's white when I open the form again.
Any idea? I'm really new to this.

Thanks.

Comment: What has led you to believe that saving data from the grid “also” saves the row color? I do not see any code that is saving the rows color. What criteria determines what each rows color should be? In most cases, coloring the rows is done “after” the data has been read. However, you could also “save” this coloring, it would depend on what determines the color. If a value in the row dictates “what” color the row should be, then saving the color is unnecessary, however, you could save the color if you wanted. Point being… simply “saving” the data in the grid is NOT going to save the rows color.

Comment: I just don't know how to do it :-) .
What row has which colour determines my click on the button (3 and 4 in code above).
Because I need to manually confirm that this row is solved.
When I click solved - it turns green and adds current date+time. When I want to "reset"  I use button 4 to remove the date and time and colour it back to white.

Comment: If the “Solved” `DateTime` field in the data is used to determine the color. Then “after” the data is loaded into the grid, loop through the rows and check each “Solved” field. If the `Solved` field has a date, and this date is “before” the current date, then color that row. I will assume that “Solved” may also be `null` or empty… in which case that would mean… DO NOT color that row.

Comment: Can you show the code that is writing the data back to the XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should color the rows as described in my comments.

```
Private Sub ColorRows()
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If (Not row.IsNewRow) And (row.Cells("Solved").Value IsNot DBNull.Value) Then
      row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

You could call this code in the forms `Load` event right after the data has been loaded into the grid. Something like…

```
….
DataGridView1.DataSource = table
ColorRows()
```

Edit...

After some testing, it appears that when the code is setting the "Solved" value to an empty string, in the `Button4_Click` event with...

```
DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Solved").Value = ""
```

This is setting a default min Date value as you noted in the xml file.

Change this line of code to...

```
DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Solved").Value = DBNull.Value
```

It should work as expected then.

Below is the complete code I used to test this.

```
Dim table As New DataTable("Table")
ReadOnly p As String = Path.Combine("D:\Test\XML\_test_100.xml")

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  DataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect
  If Not File.Exists(p) Then
    table.Columns.Add("Company", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Date", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
    table.Columns.Add("Code", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Position", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Note", Type.GetType("System.String"))
    table.Columns.Add("Solved", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"))
  Else
    table.ReadXml(p)
  End If
  DataGridView1.DataSource = table
  ColorRows()
End Sub

Private Sub ColorRows()
  For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
    If (Not row.IsNewRow) And (row.Cells("Solved").Value IsNot DBNull.Value) Then
      row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
    End If
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub btnWriteToXML_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnWriteToXML.Click
  table.WriteXml(p, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
End Sub


Private Sub btnSolved_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSolved.Click
  DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen
  DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Solved").Value = DateTime.Now
  'DataGridView1.DataSource = table
  DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
End Sub

Private Sub btnRepairSolved_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnRepairedSolved.Click
  DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
  DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Solved").Value = DBNull.Value
  'DataGridView1.DataSource = table
  DataGridView1.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```

Comment: You should probably use the `RowPrePaint` / `RowPostPaint` or `CellFormat` events to avoid repeating this each time something changes in the grid. I.e., to automate the process.

Comment: I hate to disagree with you @Jimi. Those events get fired often like when the user moves the cursor over the grid or the user scrolls the grid. Why burden those events with this “date checking code” when the cells value has not changed? This change is ONLY needed if the date changes and in this case the value is only changed by one of the buttons clicks. I am guessing I may be missing something.

Comment: @LM Rig... How is the code saving the date data to the DB? I did not go to the trouble to create a DB to test this.

Comment: Works great, except for that "repair" button. When I set Solved, it's green and stays like that. Then I press button4 and it's white again and datetime is removed but when I reopen the form it's green again. What to do to fix this? :-D Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's XML, not DB. "("C:\test.xml")" from above.

Comment: Then how is the code saving the data to the XML?

Comment: Note the *should probably* part. I don't really know whether the OP wants to automate this process or not. It looks like it (when stuff is loaded back). Anyway, changing the Color of a Cell or Row in the `RowPrePaint` or `RowPostPaint` events doesn't add any overhead in this context: the Grid has to do it anyway, it just uses what you specify instead of the default. A bit different if the `CellFormatting` event is used, since it's raised more often (much more), so you usually avoid *heavy* code there. Changing the Color is not actually *heavy work*, but it's done twice in this case.

Comment: @JohnG EDITED: Here is that XML - https://pastebin.com/WDjcTRu1 . And this is code from Form:
Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        table.WriteXml(p, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

Comment: @JohnG I see there is still <Solved>0001-01-01T00:00:00+01:00</Solved> even when I Used         DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells("Solved").Value = "" That must be problem.

Comment: @Jimi, I may have the wrong approach, however, often times I see answers that use the `CellFormating` to do things like this… and then they wonder why the UI starts lagging. I was under the impression you need to careful about what code you put in those events to prevent overwhelming the UI. My philosophy is if it only needs to be done “once,” then re-doing it when it is not needed is just putting more “unnecessary” work on the UI. If one was to ignore this philosophy (which many do), it is not surprising to see a sluggish UI. Again, I may be missing something.

Comment: For sure you should avoid, as mentioned, *heavy work* in the event handlers (any event handler, not just here). But, in this context, the events are raised to let you do your part in what the Grid does anyway: when the Row is painted, you can *participate* and draw parts of it. When the Cell is formatted (and it's formatted anyway), you can specify a different behavior (so you handle the formatting, not the Grid). Of course you don't add irrelevant - or simply *wrong* - code (code that performs completely different tasks) in these handlers. -- The question is about rendering Rows, so...

Comment: `CellFormating` is raised quite often, so should be *handled* with care. `RowPrePaint` and `RowPostPaint` not so much (way less), but it doesn't mean one can be *careless*.

Comment: @Jimi, I will agree that in most cases (like this one) the changing of the color will be trivial and not affect the UI using any of the event you mentioned. This however depends on “what” the code is doing AND how much data is there. If you have a grid with millions of rows, then this unnecessary checking and setting of the color “may” have an impact. My point is doing it “right” the first time regardless of what the code is doing or how much data is there... is the way to go. Convenience is no excuse to push your work onto the UI.

Comment: @Jimi, also I thank you for your comments and I am confident we are both on the same page and are simply comparing apples to oranges. I just want to be clear that I am NOT arguing with you about any of this. I have been wrong in the past and I will assume I may be wrong here also.

Comment: Sure, you have no *obligations* to agree to anything (you can test though :). Also, I'm not *explaining*, I'm just trying to share something I know. -- In this case, as mentioned, if you handle the drawing of the Rows (and you draw parts or all of it) or the Formatting of Cells (and you specify a Format) using the Arguments that the events provide, you don't *add overhead*, you *replace* the same action that the Grid would perform anyway. Of course, as also mentioned, you avoid code that's doing something completely different or doesn't use these methods the way they're meant to be used.

Comment: @JohnG Don't you also know how to fix these wrong data about Solved row? :-)

Comment: I am trying to test your code, however you have not added the code that "writes" the data back to the XML file as I have requested. In my test it is unclear how the line  ... `table.ReadXml(p)` ... works. I keep getting an error since `table` has no columns. Point being... if the code is "saving" the data with your changes... where is that code? Please post that code in your question.

Comment: Please see my update in my answer. I am still not sure how you are not getting an error if the xml file exist. In the current code since the `DataTable` `table` has no columns I would think you would get an error on the line... `table.ReadXml(p)` ..., or at least I was getting an error.

Comment: Ahh... i finally see the write in the comment... you should add that code to your question as a comment may be missed. Last update using your code with small changes..

Comment: @JohnG Ok, I'll next time. You are the best, the last modification works perfectly :-) .
Thank you for your time!